# componentDidMount() not working in reactJs v15.x

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use componentDidMount to set data from axios to component state but it doesn't work

I checked it by this simple code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    state:{
      textures:null
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      let data = axios.get('http://127.0.0.0:8000/wall)
                .then(res => {
        this.setState({textures:res}
      });

      )
      }
  render() {
    return (this.state.textures);
  }
}

export default new App();
```

in index.js

```
import App from '/app.js';

console.log(App.render());
```

the output is `null`

Comment: use `useEffect` hook instead of componentDidMount

Comment: Please, add more code (component calling ```componentDidMount``` and how are you using said component) and explain why it didn't work (any errors? simply not doing anything?).

Comment: i update description

Comment: U forgot to close the single colon(') in the url

Comment: i will edit in description because its already solved in source code

Answer (score 0):

Move your state object to the class property from the constructor.

Your constructor has its local state variable which has nothing to do with component state.

You have to either set the property from the constructor or intialize from the class.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        textures: null
     }
............
```

Comment: in class property said : not valide ?

Comment: i tried console.log() inside the componentDidMount() and no logs

Comment: i did it my friend , compiled failed ! > state ... not valide

Comment: I have updated the answer, remove semicolon from the textures, textures: null